# How do I run a function on multiple SQL Server databases?

Tags: function, sql-server-2005

I have a function that returns a single row in SQL Server. Now I have several (about a couple hundred) databases on that server with the same table structure. I want to run that function on all the databases. Is it necessary to create the function in each database, or is there another way?

This is on SQL Server 2005, btw.

I'm not at liberty to post the actual function, but it's just an SQL Server function that returns a row. Something similar to this

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getTotalOrdersByProductID](@ProductID bigint, @month varchar(100), @year varchar(100))
RETURNS @retTotalOrder TABLE
(
    ProductID BIGINT primary key,
    total int
)
AS
BEGIN;

    INSERT @retTotalOrder
    SELECT ProductID, count(*) AS total
    FROM
    PRODUCTS
    WHERE PRODUCTS.orderdate BETWEEN firstDayOfMonth(@month, @year) AND lastDayOfMonth(@month, @year)
    GROUP BY ProductID

    RETURN


END;
```

Comment: Can you show you function ? what have you tried ?

Comment: I've tried executing the 'use [dbname]' statement from inside the function, that doesn't work. I've also tried using EXEC(@sql) from inside the function and attempted to execute 'use database' from inside EXEC, and even tried concatenating the database name to all references to the tables from inside EXEC(@sql), that doesn't work either - EXEC() is not allowed inside SQL Server functions

Comment: well.. I just ended up distributing the function throughout all the databases. Didn't take long with a cursor running through the list of databases. Escaped quotation marks to the nth level though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` notation

```
SELECT * FROM Server.Database1.dbo.TableName WHERE example = 12345

SELECT * FROM Server.Database2.dbo.TableName WHERE example = 12345
```

You can `UNION` the results, depends what you wants from your function.

Comment: thanks, but i'm not just running a query on different databases. I'm trying to run a function on different databases.